# regarding the working of innerHTML in for loop in jscript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

My HTML code in which I want to know what happens when I use `text` instead of `text+`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>

<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text+=cars[i]+"<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want ?

Comment: Only `text` its replace the previous added value with new one on Each time load.

Comment: in js, `a = 'lorem ipsum'` is assignment. if you write `a += 'dolor' ` , it will append `dolor` to the tail of initial value. so a will become `lorem ipsum dolor`. if you write `a = dolor` instead of `a += dolor`, it will override the `lorem ipsum` and `a` will become `dolor`

Comment: Also please do `for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
text+=cars[i]+"<br>";
} document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;` or just `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars.join('<br/>')`

Comment: when i am using document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML will it not display the content of the html for each single for loop..??I am new to this so dont mind if i being silly.

Comment: @marmeladze i know what u r saying.But if i give document.getElement part within the for loop why will it not print every element of the array for each itereation

Answer (score 1):

`text+=cars[i]`

What this code means is that you are adding the i'th index of the cars array to the end of the string 'text'. It could be rewritten as the following,

`text = text + cars[i]`

so `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;` tells the browser to write the contents of the `text` variable inside an HTML with `id = "demo"`

for each iteration of the `for` loop value of the `text` variable is passed in. Because `text+=cars[i]+"<br>";` is before the `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;` this value changes from according to the element residing in the `i` index of the `cars` array.

at the first iteration `i = 0` so first element of the array `BMW` becomes the value of `text` and gets passed in to `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;`

in the second iteration i = 1 and the value of the `text` becomes `Volvo` and so on so fort until you reach the end of the array and `i < cars.length` is not true anymore and control exits the `for` loop.

Comment: yeah i know that part..my doubt is with document.getElement part in the for loop.How it works in each loop??

Comment: thank u for u r reply and ur time for the explanation.I already know all this .my doubt to be clear is what happens when i give text=cars[i]+"<br>" and document.getElement part with in the loop .why wont it print all the array elements one by one as happens in most of the languages

Comment: because you are concatenating every value so the final value is `"BMW"<br> "Volvo"<br> "Saab"<br> "Ford"<br> "Fiat"<br> "Audi"<br>` and that is what gets printed. if you use `text=cars[i]+"<br>"` all you will pass would be the final value of the `text` which is `Audi`

Comment: this is not a print statement like you would use in Java. you are not essentially printing this value at every iteration, you are changing the value of the `text` so the final value is the only one it matters at the end of iteration

Comment: If you feel this concept is confusing just take the `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;` out of loop and place it right after the loop :) also if the answer is satisfying please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator is the [**assignment operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators). It assigns a value to a variable, overwriting the old value:

```
var a = 'Hello, ';
a = 'World!';
console.log(a); // logs 'World!'
```

The `+=` operator is the **addition assignment operator**. It adds a value to the value of a variable:

```
var a = 'Hello, ';
a += 'World!';
console.log(a); // logs 'Hello, World!'
```

It's equivalent to:

```
var a = 'Hello, ';
a = a + 'World!';
console.log(a); // logs 'Hello, World!'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you replace text+ with text then you will get **Audi** as output.

If your question is though the text+ and **innerHTML** is given in loop but still it is not getting appended twice? then the answer is - innerHTML works in such a way that it overrides the existing values.